# How can i create a Sales order in Acumatica from Purchase Order Screen

Tags: acumatica

I'm still new in Acumatica Framework and i need some help with this project I'm working on , What im trying to do is to create a sales order that includes the components of a Kit Item entered in the Purchase Order , all that within the customization on the screen is it even possible ,

i thought about creating a BQL that would retrieve the data from the Kit Table , and then modify the BLC to create a sales order with with this data , but i'm confused from where to start

any help will be much appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add salesorder with Kit items,

But if you want to create with all components one by one, you need to follow these steps in your customization.

- Create Sales Order BLC, Add Header Information to the document cache
- Read the KIT Items added in your specific PO For each KIT item, query 
    the components from Related table which matches the version and
  add    as lines with the calculated quantity to the transaction cache as lines
- save your SO

Is this what you are looking forward?